# How to tint a png image with an alpha channel?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to code the typical dvd bouncing screensaver. I am happy with it but I want to change the color of the logo everytime it hits the wall. I have used fill(), but the logo changes to a colored rectangle. I want to change the color of the logo, respecting the alpha channel of the image.

```
from pygame import *
import random

#set canvas size variables
width = 700
height = 450

#draw canvas
screen = display.set_mode((width,height))
display.set_caption('Graphics')

#initial XY coordinates where game starts
x = random.randint(1, width)
y = random.randint(1, height)

#import logo
logo_img = image.load('dvd_logo_alpha.png')

R = 255
G = 255
B = 255

def logo(x,y):
    screen.blit(logo_img, (x,y))

def Col():
    R = random.randint(100,255)
    G = random.randint(100,255)
    B = random.randint(100,255)

#speed of the logo
dx = 3
dy = 3

endProgram = False

while not endProgram:
    for e in event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            endProgram = True

    #speed changes position XY
    x += dx
    y += dy

    #detection of collision with border of screen
    if y<0 or y>height-47:
        dy *= -1
        R = random.randint(100,255)
        G = random.randint(100,255)
        B = random.randint(100,255)
    if x<0 or x>width-100:
        dx *= -1
        R = random.randint(100,255)
        G = random.randint(100,255)
        B = random.randint(100,255)

    screen.fill((0))
    logo_img.fill((R,G,B)) #here is the problem I can not solve
    logo(x,y)
    display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to create an image with an alpha channel, to make the transparent area of the png image invisible. Use [pygame.Surface.convert_alpha()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha) To create an surface with an alpha channel:

```py
tintImage = image.convert_alpha()
```

To tint an image by  [`pygame.Surface.fill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill), the `special_flags` has too be set to `BLEND_RGBA_MULT`. This causes that the all the pixels of the image are multiplied by the color, rather then set by the color:

```py
tintImage.fill((R, G, B, 255), None, BLEND_RGBA_MULT)
```

Note, since the image has to be tint by different colors, the original image has to be kept. Use the function `logo` to copy the image, and "tint" an "blit" the copy of the image:

```py
def logo(x, y, color):
    tintImage = logo_img.convert_alpha()
    tintImage.fill((R, G, B, 255), None, BLEND_RGBA_MULT)
    screen.blit(tintImage, (x, y))
```

Call the function in the main loop of the program:

```py
endProgram = False
while not endProgram:
    for e in event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            endProgram = True

    #speed changes position XY
    x += dx
    y += dy

    #detection of collision with border of screen
    if y<0 or y>height-47:
        dy *= -1
        R = random.randint(100,255)
        G = random.randint(100,255)
        B = random.randint(100,255)
    if x<0 or x>width-100:
        dx *= -1
        R = random.randint(100,255)
        G = random.randint(100,255)
        B = random.randint(100,255)

    screen.fill((0))

    #logo_img.fill((R,G,B)) #here is the problem I can not solve
    logo(x, y, (R, G, B))

    display.update()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It does work now!! I have learned a lot. Thanks:)

Comment: Hello, I would like to know if there's a performance impact with tintImage.fill((R, G, B, 255), None, BLEND_RGBA_MULT) I see you are running this code in the loop once but if I've got multiple occurences of that in my code, will it be bad ?